# "ld" broken (downlevel?) on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I've attempted to build g++ v5.1.0 on my Centos 6 system.   The build seems to have worked, but when I try to compile and >link< a program, the linker fails thus:

```
[seesdev@sees15-lin ~]$ g++ -o testcpp testcpp.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do I have to get a newer version of "ld"?   How?

Comment: Probably depends how you configured the gcc build.

Comment: @trojanfoe, not gcc, but binutils.